How to create a 400 MHz synced clock from 1200 MHz in Verilog?
I'm trying to generate a 400 MHz synced clock from 1200 MHz.
`timescale 1ns/1ps

parameter CLOCK = 0.833; //1.2
parameter CLOCK3 = 2.50; //400

module test;
reg clk;
reg clk2;
reg clk3;

reg [31:0] cnt;
initial begin
clk = 0;
clk2 =0;
clk3 =0;
end

always #(CLOCK/2) clk = ~clk;

always@ (posedge clk) # (CLOCK3/2) clk2 = ~clk2;

endmodule

I'm trying to generate a 400 MHz posedge synchronised clock (clk2) from 1200 MHz (clk).
I check the frequency of clk2 is different from 400 MHz even that was not synced to the posedge clock.
How do I create the clock correctly?

Desired:


Is this a school assignment or a real life need? For a real life need, you'd certainly want to use a PLL.

@dim how will a PLL help?

@Andyaka: You use a PLL to generate multiple related clocks because then the synthesis tools can make guarantees about the timing relationships among them.

@Andyaka In FPGAs, logic lines and clock lines don't have the same characteristics. Generating clocks from logic is generally frowned upon, especially for such high frequencies, because the guarantees in stability/jitter/distribution/fanout aren't the same at the output of logic blocks and at the output of clock generators (like PLL). Besides, if you need the 400MHz and the 1200MHz synced together, clearly you can't achieve this with logic, due to the added delay. This will make your design unstable, unless you add the overhead to cross clock domains.

Since you used the testbench tag, I assume this is purely for Verilog simulation only.
If you want both edges of clk2 to be aligned with an edge of clk, you can use a counter and trigger off either edge of clk:
`timescale 1ns/1ps

parameter CLOCK = 0.833; //1.2

module test;
reg clk;
reg clk2;

reg [2:0] cnt;
initial begin
    clk  = 0;
    clk2 = 0;
    cnt  = 0;
end

always #(CLOCK/2) clk = ~clk;

always @(clk) begin
    if (cnt == 2) begin
        cnt = 0;
    end else begin
        cnt = cnt + 1;
    end
end

always @(clk) begin
    if (cnt == 0) begin
        clk2 = ~clk2;
    end
end

endmodule

This matches your desired waveform.

I don't know which board you use and where the input clock comes from. But I think clock wizard ip will help you for this. During implementation, you may receive some errors depending on the clock source, that is, the input clock may need to pass through a buffer. Buffer type may also vary depending on whether the input clock is differential or single ended. You can find this by selecting the relevant FPGA chip from the language templates section. If you only want to see it on the test bench, you can look at many applications on the internet.
